# Compilation problem with std::async using g++8 and c++20

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++, c++20

I am trying to use `std::async`. I have written this code

```
template<transport_type tt>
void stop_update_distances(const std::vector<stop>& stops, stop& from, const general_s& s, const osrm_machine& machine){
//...not important code...
}

void tt_map::update_distances(pqxx::connection& conn, const general_s& s,
    const osrm_machine& walk_machine, const osrm_machine& car_machine){

  std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
  futures.reserve(stops.size());

  for(stop& from : stops){
    auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, stop_update_distances<CAR>, stops, from, s, car_machine);
    futures.push_back(res);          
  }

}
```

but g++8 returned me this error

```
src/lib/tt_map.cpp: In member function ‘void kp::mp::tt_map::update_distances(pqxx::connection&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&, const kp::osrm_machine&)’:
src/lib/tt_map.cpp:383:108: error: no matching function for call to ‘async(std::launch, <unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<kp::mp::stop>&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&)’
           auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, stop_update_distances<CAR>, stops, from, s, car_machine);
                                                                                                            ^
In file included from src/lib/tt_map.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1712:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...)’
     async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1712:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/future: In substitution of ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = void (&)(const std::vector<kp::mp::stop>&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&); _Args = {std::vector<kp::mp::stop, std::allocator<kp::mp::stop> >&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&}]’:
src/lib/tt_map.cpp:383:108:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1712:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::vector<kp::mp::stop>, kp::mp::stop, kp::general_s, kp::osrm_machine))(const std::vector<kp::mp::stop>&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&)>’
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1745:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...)’
     async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1745:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/future: In substitution of ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::launch; _Args = {void (&)(const std::vector<kp::mp::stop, std::allocator<kp::mp::stop> >&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&), std::vector<kp::mp::stop, std::allocator<kp::mp::stop> >&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&}]’:
src/lib/tt_map.cpp:383:108:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1745:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::launch(void (*)(const std::vector<kp::mp::stop>&, kp::mp::stop&, const kp::general_s&, const kp::osrm_machine&), std::vector<kp::mp::stop>, kp::mp::stop, kp::general_s, kp::osrm_machine)>’
```

which I don't really understand.

I have followed the example in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). Even though it doesn't work.

Thank you for any hint, what is wrong.

Comment: is CAR a complete type?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie CAR is part a case of an enum. Therefore I think, CAR is a complete type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` and similar classes by default make copies of their arguments, and pass them along to the thread function by value. This is probably not what you want here. The specific cause of the compiler error is that `stop_update_distances` takes `stop& from` parameter by non-const reference, and a temporary copy cannot be passed there.

It's hard to tell without knowing how `stop_update_distances` is expected to use its parameters, but my guess is, you probably want to pass them along by reference. You do this by wrapping them in `std::ref` or `std::cref` as needed. Something like this:

```
 auto res = std::async(
    std::launch::async,
    stop_update_distances<CAR>,
    std::cref(stops),
    std::ref(from),
    std::cref(s),
    std::cref(car_machine));
```

Be careful with lifetime and access synchronization issued - you are now sharing objects between threads.